# Optimizing R Code

Tags: coordinate-system, r, optimization

I am trying to run this code:

```
bw.choice <-
  bw.gwpca(
  data = d1s,
  vars = colnames(d1s@data),
  k = kVal,
  dMat = distances,
  adaptive = TRUE
)
```

d1s is (72,000 x 11 (13 with coordinates))

I am running out of memory and this will not execute (seems like it is stuck in endless loop). I have an 2022 M1 MacBook Pro with 16gb of memory.

I am not very familiar with SpatialPointDataFrames, or GWPCAs. This is my first time testing it after doing other dimension reduction methods.

This is the documentation I am following: https://rpubs.com/lexcomber/SpatAcc_GWPCA3

I am wondering if there is a way to do this in parallel, or other alternatives to speed up (and actually execute) the computation.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please do not delete questions that have been closed, and then re-ask them.  We need you to edit the original question so that those edits may be reviewed to determine if the question is ready to be re-opened.  Please check out our short [Tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.